# how to use seperator in python when string multiplied by integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

`print('python'*5,sep=',')`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB3HT.png

How do I print it on a new line?

Ex: pythonpythonpythonppythonpython

But it's not using `'sep=','` option
so, how do I get it working ?

ex: python,python,python,....

Comment: `print('python\n'*5)`

Comment: `sep=','` is an argument for the `print` function, it has no relation to the expression `'python' * 5`.

Comment: You can use ``print(*['python']*5,sep=',')``, or ``print(','.join(['python']*5))``, or ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
print(*5*('python',), sep=',')
```

Output

> python,python,python,python,python

You have to add the ',' to let the separator know what to separate, otherwise it will think there's only one word.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do so. Try

```
'python, ' * 5
```

or

```
print(*['python']*5,sep=',')
```

or

```
', '.join(['python'] * 5)
```

`sep` is an argument of `print()` function and not a string formatter. It puts the separator when print's work is done.